# How do you use command "FOR" in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line

So say I have a directory structure like this,

```
\folder 1\  
\folder 1\folder A\  
\folder 2\  
\folder 2\folder B\
```

So forth..

Within each directory there are files `*.abc` and `*.xyz`. For every `*.abc` or `*.xyz` file under the directory I need to run `program.exe` and save its result in this manner,

```
program.exe -argumen1 -argument2 [*.abc or *.xyz] >> Text.txt
```

My question is how to do this in one command under Windows CMD? Looks like `for` is the one I should be using but the built-in help guide is rather confusing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I do this?

> Within each directory there are files *.abc and *.xyz. For every *.abc or *.xyz file under the directory I need to run "program.exe" and save the result in this manner ...

Batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /b /s *.abc *.xyz`) do (
  program.exe -argument1 -argument2 %%i >> Text.txt
  )
)
endlocal
```

Command line:

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in (`dir /b /s *.txt *.cmd`) do @echo program.exe -argument1 -argument2 %i >> Text.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.